# An expression with the meaning of "don't care" and "do not make a ceremony of"

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I wanted to explain to a seller on online auction to pack the item with care because it can be damaged in transit. I looked for the right expression to say that our postal workers sometimes don't care much about packages (at least here in Russia).

In my native language, which is Russian, we use expression like "ne tseremonitsya" (не церемониться). Which is "do not make a ceremony of smth".

The online dictionary gave me examples like:

> 1. make no bones of...
> 2. handle without gloves
> 3. deal shortly
> 4. pull no punches
> 5. didn't mince matters with ...

Could you please assist me in finding a good expression?

Answer (score 3):

You can tell the shipper the item must be carefully packed because you expect the package to undergo *rough handling* while in transit, or expect that it might be *mishandled, mistreated,* or *thrown about*.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://thesaurus.babylon.com/careless) are dozens upon dozens of synonyms for *careless* at babylon.com, but I have to say that unless OP specifically wants a slang/idiomatic usage, *careless* probably fits the bill.

The idiom I'd go for is [ham-fisted](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=ham+fisted&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&psj=1&ei=qS4jT9HDGJPd8QOO5-DbBw&ved=0CCAQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=a8cc55938fdce19c&biw=1305&bih=843) *- lacking physical movement skills, especially with the hands*.

Comment: That's a fine list of synonyms, except that many are synonymous with the uncommon "not interested" sense of *careless*, rather than its common "reckless" aspect.  For example,  *[pococurante](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pococurante)* is synonymous with *aloof, apathetic, disinterested, indifferent, nonchalant* but not with *reckless*.

Comment: @jwpat7: I certainly didn't mean to suggest that *all* those "synonyms" would match OP's requirement - I really just wanted to get across the idea that there are a *lot* of (standard *and* slang) terms covering the general area. Plus glancing through them is a good way to drive home the point that the word *careless* itself covers a broad spectrum. Specifically for OP, there's the spread from *having no regard for* to *handling roughly or clumsily*, all of which probably apply to what he wants to convey.